# Don't show images inserted into content

Tags: images, shortcode, gallery

I'm using a lightbox plugin to display my post images with `[gallery]`, it works
but those images show up in the content area too.

So there are thumbnails and full size of same image.
 How can i hide images from content?
http://guide2nepal.com/packages/island-peak/

Comment: Do you have a link to the website it's on so I could take a closer look?

Comment: there are three thumbnails, one is featured image so it doesn't show up in the content. Other 2 images i "inserted into the post".

Comment: so to confirm, do you have the [gallery] shortcode in the post AND those 2 images 'inserted'?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** I uploaded images and didn't click "Insert into post", not even "Save all Changes" and it works now.

Comment: Yeah I was about to say, that's all you needed to do :)

Comment: Be sure to click the checkmark next to answer to indicate that your question has been solved.